# Ubuntu 16.04 server custom service

Tags: service, daemon, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

There is a way for create custom service in ubuntu 16.04?
I want something autostart at startup, manageable with `service mycustomservice start`

And the service should start a php websocket: ([php ratchet](http://socketo.me/))

```
php -f socket.php
```

Comment: at least can you tell me why downvote? just for understand. I've search on google but nothing.

Comment: try   to use crontab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `supervisor` [enter link description here](http://supervisord.org/)

```
[program:ratchet]
command                 = bash -c "ulimit -n 10000; exec /usr/bin/php ./bin/tutorial-terminal-chat.php"
process_name            = Ratchet
numprocs                = 1
autostart               = true
autorestart             = true
user                    = root
stdout_logfile          = ./logs/info.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 1MB
stderr_logfile          = ./logs/error.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 1MB
```